# Align one equation left, center the other

Tags: align, alignment

I want to write the formulation

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\text{Find } u_{h} \in S_{h,0}^{1} \text{ such that} \\
a(u_{h},v_{h}) = l(v_{h}) \qquad \forall v_{h} \in S_{h,0}^{1}
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

[image]

However the first line should be left aligned, while the second remains centered and the spacing between them and the common equation number remains the same. Can this be done somehow?

Comment: I think i missed that with left align i mean align the first line to the left margin

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx,  You should simply treat the first line as part of the previous paragraph.  None of the math there requires display style, and it's logically an explanation.  Then the remaining line should be entered with the `equation` environment.

Comment: @Christian: "the common equation number"? Sentence elements like "Find ... such that" doesn't need (or, rather, shouldn't have) a number. Would you agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite what you want (the equation number is on the 2nd line), with `\shortintertext`from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\shortintertext{Find $ u_{h} \in S_{h,0}^{1} $ such that}
a(u_{h},v_{h}) = l(v_{h}) \qquad \forall v_{h} \in S_{h,0}^{1}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think i will go with that, the centered equation number seems a little bit odd now as i see it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Building on @barbarabeeton's suggestion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Find $u_{h} \in S_{h,0}^{1}$ such that
\begin{equation}
a(u_{h},v_{h}) = l(v_{h})\ \forall\ v_{h} \in S_{h,0}^{1}\,.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Do you possibly intend to produce the following output?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    A\par A 
    \begin{align}
        \begin{split}
            &\text{Find $u_{h} \in S_{h,0}^{1}$ such that} \\
            &a(u_{h},v_{h}) = l(v_{h}) \qquad \forall v_{h} \in S_{h,0}^{1}
        \end{split}
    \end{align}
    A\par A
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements seem a bit strange to me, I mean, why do you want the equation number centered between a text line and a math line? Anyway, here is one way to do it, use text mode for the first line and subtract a vertical space of `\baselineskip + \abovedisplayskip` to use `gathered` in mathmode with the first line empty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

A\par A

Find $u_{h} \in S_{h,0}^{1}$ such that
\par\addvspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\abovedisplayskip}
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\\
a(u_{h},v_{h}) = l(v_{h}) \qquad \forall v_{h} \in S_{h,0}^{1}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

A\par A

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Now as I see it the centered equation number seems a little bit odd to me and I will probably go with the solution from Bernard, but that is obviously my fault.